# Input redirection from non-existent file to fopen()

Tags: c, bash, input, io-redirection

I'm working on a CTF puzzle and I'm stuck on a "File Input" piece. The code that I'm trying to pass:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("\x0a", "r");
if(!fp) return 0;
if(fread(buf, 4, 1, fp) != 1) return 0;
if(memcmp(buf, "\x00\x00\x00\x00", 4)) return 0;
fclose(fp);
```

It's attempting to open a file named `\x0a` (i.e. a newline character) which doesn't exist, one of the limitations also being that I can't create said file.

I've tried redirecting file-descriptors to the program but it doesn't seem to work.

```
echo -e "\x00\x00\x00\x00" | ./input 4>&0 63>&0
```

I'm trying the file descriptors `4` and `63` from the outputs of `ls /dev/fd` and `bash -c 'echo <(echo)'` respectively.

Is this approach wrong? Is there another way to *simulate* a non-existent file through input redirection?

Comment: Is the program dynamically linked to libc?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yeah, it looks like it is; `readelf -a` shows a handful of GLIBC and libc.so entries under imports/shared libraries

Comment: You cannot use input redirection to alter the appearance of the filesystem to a program.  Redirection takes place before the program starts.  When the program calls `open(2)`, it gets a brand-new file descriptor; it does not reuse an already-open one.  The most you can do with this technique is use up all the available fds, so it fails with `EMFILE` instead of `ENOENT`.

Comment: @Kevin I was under the impression, from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) and multiple other sources, that you could redirect *any* file descriptor. Is that not the case?

Comment: If it's dynamically linked, you can do quite a bit by getting in between the application and the implementation of fopen() in th C library with LD_PRELOAD or similar - basically, open a pty or pipe or something instead of the filename it passes. For example, the fakeroot tool does this to build archives with contents apparently owned by root, by getting between the build and archive tools and the actual filesystem in this way.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm not sure how to approach what you're saying; are you saying that I could create a pipe (via `mkfifo`) and then attach that to a file descriptor?

Comment: @newfurniturey: You can redirect any file descriptor.  `open(2)` (and by extension `fopen(3)`) will never return a file descriptor that has been redirected (unless you `close(2)` it so the redirect is no longer in effect).  If no empty file descriptor is available, you get `EMFILE`.  Listen to the people telling you to mess with `LD_PRELOAD`.  The only (obvious) way to do this is to change the behavior of `fopen(3)`/`open(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments said, input redirection is made just before the program starts.  It is made from the shell that launches the program, so you cannot change it from the program.

To get a file with name "\n", just do:

```
$ echo "whatever you want to put in the file" >"
> "
```

and you'll get a file named `"\n"`

Also, it's not good to use `\0` inside a string literal, as the compiler adds an extra `'\0'` at the end of the string, so you can get stuck on having five `\0`s instead of four.

Finally, remember that you cannot redirect the files you open inside your program. File redirection is something happens to the files your program receives already open, normally `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`.  You can redirect others, but you have to assume you receive normally open only descriptors for these standard files.

When you do `./input 4>&0 63>&0` you are `dup(2)`ing standard input (descriptor `0`, most probably, the terminal you are executing that command from) to descriptor `4` and `63`, nothing happens to the file you open inside your program.

Comment: That's good and all, except I can't create any files (that's part of the CTF limitations). Everything has to be done through redirection of some-sort.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand acronyms, what does CTF mean? I cannot fully understand what you mean with redirection then.

Comment: "Capture the Flag"; it's like a puzzle or game where you have a specific goal to meet under certain conditions. In this stage, the program is reading a file that doesn't exist and I don't have the ability to create files, so there has to be an alternative way to do it... I hope =P

Comment: thanks.  I don't understand then the need of such a file with a \n in the name.